# Display searchform in the menu

Tags: menus

I'm trying to display the searchform in my both menus. But it display only on the **Primary** menu and not on "**top-menu-deconnecte**". Do you know why ?

```
 function wpgood_nav_search($items, $args) {
     if( !($args->theme_location == 'primary' ) || !($args->theme_location == 'top-menu-deconnecte' )) 
     return $items;
     return $items . '<li class="well-search_top">' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
 }
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpgood_nav_search', 10, 2);
```

Comment: If doesn't equal primary OR doesn't equal top-menu-deconnecte - that's what your code is saying. What is actually happening / not happening?

Comment: I want to display searchform in both menus. I use 2 menus on the same theme location : Primary for user logged in and "top-menu-deconnecte" for user not logged in. I'm a bit lost with statements.

Comment: try flipping your if - if equals primary or equals top-menu-deconnecte then return with search else return?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok with

```
 function wpgood_nav_search($items, $args) {
     if( ($args->theme_location == 'primary' ) or ($args->theme_location == 'top-menu-deconnecte' )) {
     return $items . '<li class="well-search_top">' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
 } else {
    return $items;
 }
}
```